# Insert an array in an existing object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have data from MYSQL which i use WHILE loop to get all the rows i want.

```
while($row_metro_address_country_name = $res_metro_address_country_name->fetchRow()) { 


        $notice['data'][] = array("more_images" => "<div class=\"swiper-slide\"><img class=\"avatar\" src=\"".$row_metro_address_country_name[0]."\"></div>");

                    }
```

i have an already existing object with arrays.How do i add the above result of MYSQL array into this one.

```
$notice['data'][]  = array("by" => author($row_metro_company_doc_legal[1]),
                "property_price"=>$property_price,
                "nickname"=>parse($row_metro_company_doc_legal[5]),
                "more_images"=>$fimg);
```

As a result i get

```
{
    "err_code": 0,
    "err_msg": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "more_images": "<div class=\"swiper-slide\"><img class=\"avatar\" src=\"http:\/\/apa.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/jspringext.jpg\"><\/div>"
        },
        {
            "more_images": "<div class=\"swiper-slide\"><img class=\"avatar\" src=\"http:\/\/apa.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/tspring2.jpg\"><\/div>"
        },
        {
            "by": "author",
            "price": "250,000",
            "nickname": "Spring Valley",
            "more_images": "<div class=\"swiper-slide\"><img class=\"avatar\" src=\"http:\/\/apa.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/jspringext.jpg\"><\/div>"
}
```

Instead of

```
{
    "err_code": 0,
    "err_msg": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "by": "author",
            "price": "250,000",
            "nickname": "Spring Valley",
            "more_images": "<div class=\"swiper-slide\"><img class=\"avatar\" src=\"http:\/\/apa.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/jspringext.jpg\"><\/div><div class=\"swiper-slide\"><img class=\"avatar\" src=\"http:\/\/apa.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/jspringext.jpg\"><\/div><div class=\"swiper-slide\"><img class=\"avatar\" src=\"http:\/\/apa.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/07\/tspring2.jpg\"><\/div>"

}
```

Comment: Adding values to an array using `$array[] = ...` will have php auto-assigning keys to the value you are adding. That way you will have a hard time connecting the right images to the right entries. You'd be better off using a key from the database for your array key so that you can identify them. Or - even better - get everything in one go from the database using a `JOIN` query.

Comment: Based on the "result" and "instead of" you show, it seems like you want to replace all inside the "data", not adding it?

Comment: @jeroen i'd be happy if you show me the right direction

Comment: @rmondesilva well not the case,i am simply trying to add more images to an array that is already existing ... i am in the desert here

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to append to the object like so

```
$notice['data']["more_images"] .= "<div class=\"swiper-slide\"><img class=\"avatar\" src=\"".$row_metro_address_country_name[0]."\"></div>";
```

Although, would you're while loop be returning multiple rows of ["data"]?

Answer (score 0):

```
$notice['data'][]  = array("by" => author($row_metro_company_doc_legal[1]),
                "property_price"=>$property_price,
                "nickname"=>parse($row_metro_company_doc_legal[5]),
                "more_images"=>$fimg);
```

Replace it with

```
$notice['data'][]  = array("by" => author($row_metro_company_doc_legal[1]),
                "property_price"=>$property_price,
                "nickname"=>parse($row_metro_company_doc_legal[5])),
                "more_images"=>array_pop($fimg));
```

Comment: i don't follow where $fimg should be